# How to access a public static final member in a Java class from Scala?

Tags: java, scala

I've been trying to run the following piece of Scala code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame

class ScalaClass(title: String) extends JFrame(title: String) {
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
  // ...
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    var sFrame : JFrame = new ScalaClass("Hi");
  }
}
```

`JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` should be equal to `3`. However, when I try to build and run in IntelliJ IDEA I recieve this error:

`Error:(4, 35) value EXIT_ON_CLOSE is not a member of object javax.swing.JFrame
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`

Adding `import javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` does not work either.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the place it's *actually* defined in, [`javax.swing.WindowConstants`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html). When the Java compiler sees `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` it's rewritten into `WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`; the Scala compiler doesn't do that (neither does Kotlin).

It used to be declared in `JFrame` but [was removed in Java 9](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8073420); it's a source- and binary-compatible change for Java, as described in the link, but not source-compatible for Scala/Kotlin.

Comment: looks like is now working on kotlin, still not on scala